# Avoiding CSV injection vulnerability in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, security, reporting-services

I'm trying to find a way to avoid CSV injection when i export a report to CSV format is SSRS (Microsoft Reporting Services).

The "manual way" to do it is to add an apostrophe (') to each cell. That will "convert" everything to text and relieve the threat of external code being executing automatically when opening the document.
But since I have many reports and I don't want to change all of them.

Is there a configuration or a setting that can help in this situation?

More about this vulnerability:

- https://www.we45.com/blog/2017/02/14/csv-injection-theres-devil-in-the-detail
- https://affinity-it-security.com/how-to-prevent-csv-injection/

Comment: What injection are you expecting here from SSRS? Seems like the place to stop the data being "bad" is at the point of inserting, not extraction.

Comment: @Larnu You are right, That is the best place to do it. But, at least in my case, it's easier to change the reports than to modify the system so it'll validate the input.

Comment: Then, in your `SELECT`, you should "sanitise" the data. SSRS is the last place you should be doing data sanitising.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, That's the "manual way" i've mentioned.

I tried changing some configuration of the csv extention in RsReportServer.config but could find something that "works" for this case.

Comment: Why doesn't sanitising it in your `SELECT` "work"?

Comment: @Larnu It does work. but i have about 30-40 reports and each report has a lot of columns.
I was hoping for a quicker way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

Please make a copy of the config file before making any change.

1.On the SSRS server, find the RSResportServer.config file.

2.Find the tag.

3.Add the attached code inside the  tags.

```
<Extension Name="PIPE" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
  <OverrideNames>
    <Name Language="en-US">CSV (Pipe delimited)</Name>
  </OverrideNames>
  <Configuration>
    <DeviceInfo>
      <FieldDelimiter>,'</FieldDelimiter>
      <FileExtension>csv</FileExtension>
    </DeviceInfo>
  </Configuration>
</Extension>
```

4.Restart the SSRS

When you want to export a report to CSV format,choose the CSV (Pipe delimited).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't customize the export settings. In terms of a workaround, sanitizing in SSRS was mentioned in the comments. You could also potentially add a separate process that safely sanitizes the outputted CSV files before they are otherwise consumed.